# Django how to call a method from a custom field given a model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class CustomField(models.CharField):
    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'

class Test(models.Model):
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    col2 = CustomField(max_length=45)
```

How can I call the `foo` method from `CustomField`, if I'm given an instance of `Test`?

For example:

```
>>> t = Test.objects.create(col1='bar', col2='blah')
>>> t.col2
'blah'
>>> t.col2.foo() # 'str' object has not attribute 'foo'
'foo'
```

This, of course, throws:

> 'str' object has not attribute 'foo'

because calling `model_instance.column` returns the *value* of that column, not an instance of `column`.

But why exactly?  It seems Django's ORM magically transforms an instance of a field class into a value.  I've spent hours digging through source code and can't seem to find where the transformation takes place.

TLDR;

Is it possible to return an instance of a field class given a model instance?

Any idea where this happens in Django's source code?  I assume this takes place in `django/db/models/base.py`, but that file is over 1800 lines of code, so it's really hard to tell.

### Update

Here is a practical example of why this would be useful:

```
class TempField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, initial_unit='C', **kwargs):
        self.initial_unit = initial_unit
        self.units = ['F', 'C', 'K']

    def convert(self, unit):
        if self.initial_unit == unit:
            return self.value

        if unit not in self.units:
            raise

        attr = getattr(self, f'_{initial_unit}_to_{unit}', None)
        if attr is None:
            raise

        return attr(unit)

        def _C_to_F(self, unit):
            ...
```

Now you can conveniently convert this field to the desired unit:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    temperature = TempField(...)

>>>t = Test.objects.create(temperature=100)
>>>t.temperature
100
>>>t.temperature.convert('F')
212
```

This is all just untested pseudo code.  Also, I can think of several ways of having this functionality without the headache of using custom fields in this manner; so this question is really about understanding how Django's ORM works, and not necessarily how to solve any real world problems.

Comment: That would be `Test.col2.foo()`. Note that the `self` here is not the value wrapped by a field, but the `CharField` object.

Comment: Can you explain why you might need this? There is certainly a better way.

Comment: Should it be assumed that `t` is the result of the `Test.objects.create(col1='bar', col2='blah')`? Which specific line throws, so obviously, `'str' object has not attribute 'foo'`?

Comment: @MikeMajara Yes, sorry that was a typo.  Updated and showed where the error would be thrown.

Comment: @CalebGoodman: I think you should fix this with another layer of indirection: instead of returning a `decimal`, you return a `Temperature` that contains a decimal and a unit, and thus has functionality to convert it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated to show a practical example

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How could I do that?  Also, wouldn't that involve changing the data type in your database?

Comment: @CalebGoodman: not per se, a Django field simply wraps database values to Python values and vice versa, so depending on the use case, you might still use the same field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This seem like an acceptable answer to me, but I'm still not sure how it can be done :)

Comment: [`django-phonenumber-field`](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) is a good example of what @WillemVanOnsem is describing.

Comment: @bromosapien thanks!  working link: [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field).  Remember: brackets always come first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a saying in computer science by *David Wheeler* that "*All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection (except too many layers of indirection)*".

We thus can define a class `Temperature` for example to store the temperature:

```
from enum import Enum
from decimal import Decimal
NINE_FIFTHS = Decimal(9)/Decimal(5)

class TemperatureUnit(Enum):
    KELVIN = (1,0, 'K')
    FAHRENHEIT = (NINE_FIFTHS, Decimal('-459.67'), '°F')
    CELSIUS = (1, Decimal('-273.15'), '°C')
    RANKINE = (NINE_FIFTHS, 0, '°R')

class Temperature:

    def __init__(self, kelvin, unit=TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS):
        self.kelvin = Decimal(kelvin)
        self.unit = unit

    @staticmethod
    def from_unit(value, unit=TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS):
        a, b, *__ = unit.value
        return Temperature((value-b)/a, unit)

    @property
    def value(self):
        a, b, *__ = self.unit.value
        return a * self.kelvin + b

    def convert(self, unit):
        return Temperature(self.kelvin, unit)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.value, self.unit.value[2])
```

For example we can here create tempratures:

```
>>> str(Temperature(15, unit=TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT))
'-432.67 °F'
>>> str(Temperature(0, unit=TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT))
'-459.67 °F'
>>> str(Temperature(1, unit=TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT))
'-457.87 °F'
>>> str(Temperature(0, unit=TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT))
'-459.67 °F'
>>> str(Temperature(0, unit=TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS))
'-273.15 °C'
```

Now we can make a Django model field that stores and retrieves `Temperature`s, by saving these for example in a decimal on the database side, in Kelvin:

```
class TemperatureField(models.DecimalField):

    def from_db_value(self, value):
        kelvin = super().from_db_value(value)
        if kelvin is not None:
            return Temperature(kelvin)
        return None

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return value
        kelvin = super().to_python(value)
        return Temperature(kelvin)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            value = value.kelvin
        return super().get_prep_value(value)
```

The above is of course a raw sketch. See the [documentation on writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) for more information. You can add a form field, widget, lookups to query the database, etc. So you can define an extra layer of logic to your `TemperatureField`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  You went above and beyond with this answer! (despite how frustrating it was to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126374/10746224) your `from_db_value`) ;)

Comment: Also I finally get what you meant by "*another layer of indirection*"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified, working version of WillemVanOnsem's [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124263/10746224):

```
class TemperatureField(models.DecimalField):

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is not None:
            return Temperature(value)
        return None

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return value
        kelvin = super().to_python(value)
        return Temperature(kelvin)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            value = value.kelvin
        return super().get_prep_value(value)

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(value.kelvin, self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
        elif isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(Decimal(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
        elif isinstance(value, (Decimal,)):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(Decimal(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)

Test(models.Model):
    temp = TemperatureField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

A few notes:

In order to save custom field types to your DB, you have to override `get_db_prep_value`, so that your model knows how to handle `Temperature` objects, otherwise, your model will think it's working with a `Decimal`, which will result in:

> AttributeError: 'Temperature' object has no attribute 'quantize'

Clear error with an easy fix...

Now, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) on `from_db_value`:

> If present for the field subclass, from_db_value() will be called in all circumstances when the data is loaded from the database, including in aggregates and values() calls.

emphasis on **when the data is loaded from the database**!

This means that when you call `t = Test.objects.create(...)`, `from_db_value` will not be evaluated, and the corresponding custom column for the `t` instance will be equal to whatever value you set it to in the `create` statement!

For example:

```
>>>t = Test.objects.create(temp=1)
>>>t.temp
1
>>>type(t.temp)
<class 'int'>

>>>t = Test.objects.first()
>>>t.temp
<extra_fields.fields.Temperature object at 0x10e733e50>
>>> type(t.temp)
<class 'extra_fields.fields.Temperature'>
```

If you tried to run the original version of `from_db_value`:

```
def from_db_value(self, value):
    kelvin = super().from_db_value(value)
    if kelvin is not None:
        return Temperature(kelvin)
    return None
```

You won't even get errors until you call:

```
>>>t = Test.objects.get(...)
TypeError: from_db_value() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'from_db_value'
```

Lastly, **note** that `from_db_value` is not a method in any of Django's base model fields, so calling `super().from_db_value` will always throw an error.  Instead the `Field` base class will check for the existence of `from_db_value`:

```
def get_db_converters(self, connection):
    if hasattr(self, 'from_db_value'):
        return [self.from_db_value]
    return []
```