# How to have create statement respect the "from_db_value" in custom Django fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a custom field, like this:

```
class Temperature:
    pass

class TemperatureField(models.DecimalField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is not None:
            return Temperature(value)
        return None

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return value
        kelvin = super().to_python(value)
        return Temperature(kelvin)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            value = value.kelvin
        return super().get_prep_value(value)

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        if isinstance(value, Temperature):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(value.kelvin, self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
        elif isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(Decimal(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
        elif isinstance(value, (Decimal,)):
            return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(Decimal(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)

class Test(models.Model):
    temp = TemperatureField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

The following works as expected when **loading data from the database**, for example:

```
>>>t = Test.objects.first()
>>>t.temp
<extra_fields.fields.Temperature object at 0x10e733e50>
>>> type(t.temp)
<class 'extra_fields.fields.Temperature'>
```

The problem is that the logic for `from_db_value` does not extend to `create` statements:

```
>>>t = Test.objects.create(temp=1)
>>>t.temp
1
>>>type(t.temp)
<class 'int'>
```

Is there a way to extend this logic to the `create` method, without overriding the model manager?  IE, can I do this within my field class?

I don't think the specifics about what the `Temperature` class does are relevant, but if you would like to know, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124263/10746224) to my other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27825#comment:9).

There's a [thread on the Django developers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/3IX1zH09Idg/discussion) that discusses it in more detail, and where the consensus is that the documentation should be updated to warn about this (this hasn't happened yet).

The solution is to either refresh the object from the database:

```
t.refresh_from_db()
```

or to force a clean on it:

```
t.full_clean()
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know they are investigating this.  After looking for a fix I realized that this is extremely difficult to problem to solve since you only have access to field methods in the db connection handler, not in the actual query methods themselves (eg `get`, `create`).