# How to add a custom method to a model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models that will use the same `CardNumberField()` to store credit card numbers. How can I add a custom method to the field to mask the card numbers?

I have created the `CardNumberField()` which inherits from `models.Charfield`:

```
# CARD NUMBER FIELD
class CardNumberField(models.CharField):
    description = _('card number')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 19
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `CardNumberField()` is then imported and used in my **customers/models.py**:

```
# CARD MODEL
class Card(models.Model):
    number = CardNumberField()
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Card [{number}]'.format(number=self.number)
```

...and in my **transactions/models.py**:

```
# TRANSACTION MODEL
class Transaction(models.Model):
    card_number = CardNumberField()
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Transaction ...'
```

So, how can I add the following method to my `CardNumberField()` to be used by both of my models?

```
def masked_number(self):
    # display masked card number
    number = self.number
    return number[-4:].rjust(len(number), '#')
```

Also, how will I grab this field method in a DRF serializer class?

Comment: You can also define an `abstract base class` for both models on wich you define the method.

Comment: I've thought about that, but I prefer not to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `contribute_to_class` method to not only contribute the field, but also include an extra method:

```
from functools import partialmethod

def _mask_number(self, field):
    number = getattr(self, field.attname)
    return number[-4:].rjust(len(number), '#')

# CARD NUMBER FIELD
class CardNumberField(models.CharField):
    description = _('card number')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 19
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
        setattr(
            cls, f'masked_{self.name}',
            partialmethod(_mask_number, field=self)
        )
```

If you add a field *`foo`* to a model class, it will automatically add a `masked_foo` method to that class. This thus also means that if you have two or more `CardNumberField`s, it will add two or more `masked_foo` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use an abstract model instead:

```py
class ModelWithCardNumber(models.Model):
   card_number = models.CharField(max_length=19)
   
   @property
   def masked_number(self):
      return self.card_number[-4:].rjust(len(number), '#')
   
   class Meta:
      abstract = True


class Card(ModelWithCardNumber):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Card [{number}]'.format(number=self.number)


class Transaction(ModelWithCardNumber):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Transaction ...'
```

Now in your serializer you can access `Card.masked_number` and `Transaction.masked_number`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer not to use an abstract model. Is there any other way to achieve the desired result? I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122830/django-how-to-call-a-method-from-a-custom-field-given-a-model-instance